# Unable to execute function at end of http request

Tags: node.js

I recreated a simple http server setup I found online (see below), but cannot get the `request.on("end", ...)` to work. It works fine if I comment that part out, but I really want to understand why it isn't working. Please help. Thanks!

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what's happening here is as follows:

1. `var http = require('http');` pulls all "exports" from the node.js `http` module and allows them to be used in this node.js simple server code.
2. `http.createServer` instantiates an object of the `http.Server` class/type.
3. `.listen(8080)` opens the server for connections at port 8080 on localhost.
4. When a user attempts to connect at port 8080, the Server object emits a request event (which is itself another event.emitter object?). That event invokes the anonymous listener function and passes `request` object to it.
5. `request.on("end", ...)` adds a listener function to the request object that looks specifically for an eventName "end". If the `end` event is emitted by the `request` object, then the anonymous function is invoked (the response is written).

---

Here is the code I used: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/nodejs-for-beginners--net-26314

---

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    request.on("end", function() {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        response.end("Hello HTTP!");
        });
}).listen(8080);
```

---

Comment: It seems like the `data` and `end` event will only be emitted if the client sends a body. E.g. submitting a form will include the form data in the request body.

Comment: Nevermind, after trying it a few more times the event sometimes gets fired and sometimes not...